# How to count received Notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an app which will count received notifications in notification bar. Till now I am done with create multiple notifications on button click ans it is showing different notifications. What i want is it shows setText when single notification and when it is multiple it will count it n shows in setText.

I tried hard to find this on Stackoverflow and other Android sites but didnot find what i am looking for. Any help would be very support full.

If anyone is not able to understand my question then please let me know.

Here is the code:

```
Button noti;
int counter = 0;
boolean ncompi = false;
//  private static int pendingNotificationsCount = 0;

NotificationManager nManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.imageclass);

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", count);
editor.putInt("counter", counter);
editor.commit();


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
int i = sharedPreferences.getInt("count", 0);
int j = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter", 0);


  Button increaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ImageClass.this);
                ncomp.setContentTitle("9999900000");
                if(counter == 0){
                    ncomp.setContentText(ss);
                    counter++;
                   // ncomp.setContentText(ss);
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ImageClass.this, MainActivity.class);

                //    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", ss);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, resultIntent, 0);

                    ncomp.setContentIntent(pi);
                    ncomp.setTicker("Notification Listener");
                    ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                    ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);

                    nManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, ncomp.build());
                }
                    else{
                         ncomp.setContentTitle("Notification");
                        ncomp.setContentText(counter + " Notifications");
                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ImageClass.this, SmsActivity.class);

                      //  resultIntent.putExtra("message", ss);
                        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, resultIntent, 0);

                        ncomp.setContentIntent(pi);
                    ncomp.setTicker("Notification Listener");
                    ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
                    nManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, ncomp.build());

                    counter++;
}
```

And also How to differ read and unread notifications in Notification Activity?

```
  ArrayList<MessageData> arrayList = new ArrayList<MessageData>();

    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, arrayList);
    smsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    MessageData data1 = new MessageData();
    data1.setMessage("");
    data1.setRead(false);
```

Created CustomListAdapter n here is the code.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<MessageData> dataList;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageData> arr){
      super();
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = arr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_spinner, null);

        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        textView.setText("" + dataList.get(position).getMessage());

        // here you can get Read/Unread status for all message
        boolean isRead = dataList.get(position).isRead();

        if (isRead) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return view;
}

}
```

Comment: see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing) if it helps.

Comment: thanks harry but i am already done with it. it is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Do you want to show count in your activity?

Comment: I want to show counts in notification bar like whatsapp, if there is single notification it show the name and if teher are multiple then it shows number like if there are 4 notifications, then it show 4 messages. I hope you got it.

Comment: if(v.getId() == R.id.btnCreateNotify){
            NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            ncomp.setContentTitle("My Notification");
            ncomp.setContentText(ss);
            ncomp.setTicker("Notification Listener");
            ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
            nManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),ncomp.build());

Comment: Its create different notifications but i want i will create only one n if more than 1 then it start counting it.

Comment: post your notification code please.

Comment: Posted above. Check it.

Comment: All my multiple notifications depend upon this code.

Comment: nManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),ncomp.build());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to see [Managing Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing) as it explains how to update notifications.
Here is what you might want:

public variables

```
final int NOTIFY_ID=1; // any integer number
int count = 0;
```

on click event:

```
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ncomp.setContentTitle("My Notification");
        if (count == 0)
            ncomp.setContentText("Notification");
        else
            ncomp.setContentText(count + " Notifications");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Message.class);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        ncomp.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        ncomp.setTicker("Notification Listener");
        ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
        nManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, ncomp.build());

        count++;
```

Hope this helped!

Edit:
To store count refer [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Thanks harry but it is not working. It creates only one notification and if i click second time it is not creating any notification

Comment: It updates notification, check in statusbar, it will also show count.

Comment: Good! Also remember to accept or vote up the answer.

Comment: Yeah sure but my reputation is less so cant vote now.

Comment: Harry one more thing I need to know, how to put intent in this notification so that when it is single notification it will open the inside page with only that person chat or if there are multiple then it will open the main page like whatsapp app.

Comment: Find 'mBuilder.setContentIntent' in given link by me, you may need to add arguments in intent. And ya, you can still accept the answer if reputation is low:)

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Message.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                
                ncomp.setContentIntent(pi);

Comment: This is the code am using, but it is not going to other activity.

Comment: you should have import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder

Comment: I am still getting issues in notifications like I am putting notifications on Broadcast n want when messages received it will get count n increment but its not working.

Comment: Help me out I need this code working very urgent. Thanks

Comment: For that you need to store the count either in cache or database to use in Broadcast.

Comment: How to store it in either cache or DB?? I am new in this so just getting knowledge.

Comment: Given a link in answer.

Comment: Apply the code edited but didnot work, do i have to implement it under MainActivity or have to create other class extends SQLite

Comment: Use SharedPreferences, just save cound in cache and then retrieve while showing notification. First understand how to use Shared preferences.

Comment: I tried to reset count of notification when notifications are clicked in notification bar using SharedPreferences but it didnot work for me ... Could you help out. Edited my code what i am doing.\